# Read multiple files from s3 faster in python

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have multiple files in s3 bucket folder. In python I read the files one by one and used concat for single dataframe. However, it is pretty slow. If I have a million of files then it will be extremely slow. Is there any other method available (like bash) that can increase the process of reading s3 files?

```
response = client.list_objects_v2(
        Bucket='bucket',
        Prefix=f'key'
        )
dflist = []

for obj in response.get('Contents', []):
    dflist.append(get_data(obj,col_name))

pd.concat(dflist)

def get_data(obj, col_name):
    data = pd.read_csv(f's3://bucket/{obj.get("Key")}', delimiter='\t', header=None, usecols=col_name.keys(),
                       names=col_name.values(), error_bad_lines=False)
    return data
```

Comment: using [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) you could read several files at the same time

Answer (score 0):

As s3 is `object storage` you need to bring your file on the computer (ie read a file in memory) and edit it and then push back again (rewrite object).

So it took some *time* to achieve your task.

some helper pointers:

1. If you process multiple files in multiple threads that will help you.
2. If your data is really heavy, start an instance on aws in the same region where your bucket is, and process data from there and terminate it. (it will save network cost + time to pull and push files across networks)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS SDK for Pandas](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html), a library that extends Pandas to work smoothly with AWS data stores. It's `read_csv` can also [read multiple csv files from an S3 folder](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/003%20-%20Amazon%20S3.html#1.3-Reading-multiple-CSV-files).

```
import awswrangler as wr
df = wr.s3.read_csv("s3://bucket/folder/")
```

It can be installed via `pip install awswrangler`.